# How to compile TypeScript/Less files into JavaScript/CSS by using webpack and Babel?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, less, bundle

Currently, I am developing a package and going to publish it in npm, I wrote it with TypeScript but faced some problems in package bundling.

I put my codes (TypeScript/Less files) in `src` and the structure shows below:

```
src
├── components
│   ├── table.less
│   └── table.tsx
├── index.tsx
└── utils
    └── mock.tsx
```

Since I want to publish it in npm, so I need it be compiled to JavaScript/CSS files (in `lib` folder) so that other developers can import it directly (without extra compiling in their project), the structure should be like this:

```
lib
├── components
│   ├── table.css
│   └── table.js
├── index.js
└── utils
    └── mock.js
```

But I faced some problems:

1. If I use `tsc` command, `tsx` files can be compiled to `js` files rightly, but `less` files will be ignored;
2. If I use webpack commands rather that `tsc`, the result will be bundled in one file, and lost it's original structure, and it will confuse package users;

I think I need to make it works by:

1. Compile all files from `src` to `lib` one by one(Keep the same folder structure);

   - `tsx` files to `js` files;
   - `less` files to `css` files;
   - add declaration files such as `index.js.d.ts` and `index.css.d.ts`;
   - modify some writing styles such as `import styles from './index.less'` to `import styles from './index.css'`; Or inject stylesheets into js files directly; (I am not sure about this step)
2. Bundle one js file with all of things in it (with webpack), as well as minimized version;

**The package contains JSX grammar since I used React in it.**

As I know, I need to use Babel in compiling TS/JS codes, and webpack in compiling less and other assets, but I am confused about how to combine them in working together.

So any suggestions on how to combine cool tools in solving my problem? I looked through really a lot tutorials but most of them are React/Less/TypeScript Project (not package development) or TypeScript package (without using less/css).

Thanks really a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been around for a long time, I hope my answer can still help people who click in to find the answer:

As you said, `.tsx` files can be compiled by `tsc` into `.ts` files, but `.scss` or `.less` not. so you need to use [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface) or [less](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage) to process them.

Based on your directory structure above, you can write the following commands under `scripts` in `package.json`:

if you use `less`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:css": "lessc src/components/table.less lib/components/table.css"
}
```

or `node-sass`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:css": "node-sass -r src -o lib"
}
```

Yes, `node-sass` scans the root folder and automatically compiles the `.scss` files in it into `.css` files in the corresponding directory. Using `less` may require you to spend more time exploring the useful methods.

But just converting to css files doesn't help, because the style files introduced in the js files still have `.less` or `.scss` suffixes, we need to replace this part of the `.js` file, you may think of using `node` to read each `.js` file, and then use the regular match, this idea is generally no problem, but the global matching of the regular replacement can cause some hidden problems (although almost impossible), so I use [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) to do the replacement.

Yes, I wrote an easy-to-use command line tool for this, you just need to:

```sh
npm i tsccss -D
```

and add npm script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:css": "node-sass -r src -o lib",
  "compile": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsccss -o lib",
  "build": "npm run build:css && npm run compile"
}
```

Yes, as you can see, `tsccss -o lib` is completely enough.

Hope you enjoy it, here is github/repo: [tsccss](https://github.com/vortesnail/tsccss)